# Which is this date format for simpledateformat (android) 2018-10-03T09:00:36.845+0000?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am getting response string 2018-10-03T09:00:36.845+0000

and i have to parse it for PrettyTime some min ago .

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

its not working, can you tell me Dateformat string to add in SimpleDateFormat ?

Here is My code

:

```
 try {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
      sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
      long time = sdf.parse(device_for_bottomviews.get(i).lastupdate).getTime();
      PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime(Locale.getDefault());
      String ago = prettyTime.format(new Date(time));
      lastupdate.setText(ago);
      } 
catch (Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
      lastupdate.setText(device_for_bottomviews.get(i).lastupdate);
}
```

exception i am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:633)
        at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:272)
        at com.test.busmanagement.MapActivity$DeviceAdapter.getView(MapActivity.java:721)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
```

Comment: What means *its not working*? Any Exception if yes please post the stackstrace. If not explain what *its not working* means

Comment: W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:633)
        at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:272)
        at com.test.busmanagement.MapActivity$DeviceAdapter.getView(MapActivity.java:721)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments, edit your original post.

Comment: Add it to your question using the edit link, not as comment

Comment: You get the excpetion in `Date.parse` not in SimpleDateFormat?! Please add a [mcve]

Comment: The classes `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are both outdated after the appearance of the `java.time` package in Java 8. Use those classes. Additionally, the constructor `Date(String)` and the factory method `Date.parse(String)` are both deprecated. And why are you setting up a `SimpleDateFormat` if you are not using it?

Comment: kindly refer post i have added my code with exceptions.

Comment: Seems to me like you want `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` (note the lack of single quotes around the `Z`).

Comment: thanks it did work.

Comment: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Similar: [org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-07-22T14:00:00-03:00' could not be parsed at index 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545720/org-threeten-bp-format-datetimeparseexception-text-2018-07-22t140000-0300). I think it could be helpful.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Date parsing, why do I get an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666263/java-date-parsing-why-do-i-get-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to quote the 'zone' part of the date format string, here is a corrected version:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format as pattern

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`

Comment: `X` is for ISO 8601 time zones. The example in the question appears to contain an RFC 822 time zone, for which you'd use `Z`.

Comment: @Michael The example in the question is pure ISO 8601.